# Receiver: null E/flutter (23903): Tried calling: []("idUsuario")

Tags: flutter, dart, null

[image: null]

por mas que quiero mostrar el nombre y el id no me deja hacerlo ... pero sí los demas campos como email phone etc que se debe?

[image: data]

Aqui se aprecia que retorna id null y nombreCompleto

[image: json]

Aqui es el error que me bota en la linea 30  con idUsuario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este el segundo error de la linea 24

Comment: Bienvenido Joseph Rueda Amaya a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Por favor, evita el uso de la imágenes y pega directamente el código en tu pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.